# Center ul without div

Tags: html, css, carousel, center

Im trying to center the circles (carousel indicators) on this [page](http://tambotest.spaces.nexudus.com/en). I tryed all, width 100%, margin auto, but nothing work.

I dont have more ideas.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the minimum code on it that reproduces the problem?  Make it runable, so we can look at it and try it and see if we can come up with some ideas.  If it doesn't work on this page, try fiddle or one of the other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your page, I don't see any circles that is not centered.
But with regards to centering ul without div, you can do so via CSS.

Example,
CSS:

```
#carousel-indicators li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    height:110px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then at your ul, specify

```
<ul id="carousel-indicators";>
```

This is not tested on carousel-indicators but it does work for image and text content under ul and li tags.